# Why my app is crashing on clicking any of the buttons?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use intents but on clicking any of the buttons,the app stops working and terminates.I am a beginner and I couldn't find the reason.I am providing my xml file,java file and menifest file.Please someone help.
here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.shreya.intents.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Alarm"
        android:id="@+id/alarm"
        android:onClick="setAlarm"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Map"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:onClick="seeMap"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mail"
        android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:onClick="email"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email ID"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:id="@+id/address"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my .java file:

```
package com.example.shreya.intents;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.AlarmClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.Locale;



import static com.example.shreya.intents.R.id.alarm;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void setAlarm(){
        String message="Wake Up";
        int hour=7;
        int minutes=0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void seeMap(){
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", 28.699884, 77.273075);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
            startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void email(){
        EditText mail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        String add=mail.getText().toString();
        composeEmail(add,"shreya");
    }

    public void composeEmail(String addresses, String subject) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"hello");
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

And finally this is my menifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace / logcat of the crash

Answer (score 3):

You have to add parameter `View view` to your `onClick` methods.

For example:

```
public void setAlarm(View view){ 

}
```

Add that parameter to other `onClick` methods also: `email` and `seeMap`.

Under the hood, the system uses reflection to figure out the exact `onClick` method in the `Activity` and the system uses the following exact pattern to find the method: a `public void` method with the specified method name in the xml `onClick` attribute and has a single parameter `View`.